# Is there a way to know what services run on a Windows server without logging in to this server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot, background-process

Hi I just started working as an intern and they use Windows servers for very specific tasks (converting .docx files) that are way harder on their other servers. But now I had to make that program run as a service. The catch is that it also runs on other Windows servers already for load balancing and I can't just check if it works by turning of the other servers as it is all live, with many clients. So is there a way (logging in doesn't guarantee it runs before I log in) to check what processes are running on the server before logging in / making a RDP connection?

Comment: You can use powershell or wmi.  You will have to use credentials to log in but its not an interactive login.  There are too many ways to answer tho question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the **Services** console (services.msc) on your PC using an account that has permissions on the target server (shift+right-click to run as different user). Right-click on the left panel where it says "Services (local)" and input the name of the target server. *BAM!* There you go.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is your best friend in this case.

Create a remote session on the server and get-services - status running would get the same result and can be used on a whole bunch of servers by using

Invoke-command

Or use the Server Manager application and Connect to the remote server using the correct credentials.

There is a section specifically for services

Answer (score 0):

To display processes:

```
Tasklist /S serverName
```